# Hammerspoon get working directory from finder

Tags: terminal, finder, automation

I am a new user of hammerspoon, I want to make a new shortcut (ctrl-alt-T) that opens the Terminal app in Finder's working directory. Do you know how can I get the working directory of Finder from hammerspoon?

Answer (score 4):

Here's some AppleScript for you:

```
tell application "Finder" to get POSIX path of (insertion location as string)
```

If you don't want to get the Desktop if a Finder window isn't active, use this instead:

```
tell application "Finder" to get POSIX path of (target of front window as string)
```

This will get the location of the **frontmost Finder window**, even if none is selected. If there are none open, **it will fail**.

I don't know how Hammerspoon works, but if it can run Terminal commands, you can use `osascript` to run the AppleScript.

---

Also, you don't need to use Hammerspoon to do this. There's already a Service for this, or you can use Automator to make your own:

- Create a new Service.
- Make it take **No Input** in **Finder.app**.
- Add a Run AppleScript action, and put this in the box:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Finder" to set p to POSIX path of (insertion location as string)
    tell application "Terminal" to do script "cd " & quoted form of p

    return input
end run
```

- Save it appropriately, like "New Terminal Here".
- Add a keyboard shortcut in System Preferences, if desired.
- Enjoy!